# Adding one row as a column to existing columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I need your help in one SQL Query for converting the example table given below. Where I need Facilities as columns.

| Seasonid | Product | Facility | Price | Product Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Socks | Montreal | 24 | Wool |
| 2 | Slippers | Mexico | 50 | Poly |
| 3 | Slippers | Montreal | 27 | Rubber |
| 4 | Socks | Mexico | 24 | Cotton |
| 5 | Socks | Montreal | 26 | Cotton |

**Below table is how I'm expecting it to look like**

| seasonid | Product | Montreal | Mexico | Product Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Socks | 24 | 0 | Wool |
| 2 | Slippers | 0 | 50 | Poly |
| 3 | Slippers | 27 | 0 | Rubber |
| 4 | Socks | 0 | 24 | Cotton |
| 5 | Socks | 26 | 0 | Cotton |

In the expected result table even though 5th row data can be accommodated in 4th row itself like

| seasonid | Product | Montreal | Mexico | Product Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Socks | 26 | 24 | Cotton |

my requirement requires it in a different row.

I found some pivot examples online, but they only show averaging or summing up the values and won't add the rows to already existing columns and display them all. I couldn't find a relevant post for this question. Please let me know if there is any relevant post.

**Is it possible with Sql in the first place? If yes, then how?**

Comment: We need to see the query and the original starting data, in addition to what you have shown above.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Original starting data looks exactly the same as the first table in question. To achieve the first table, I've written around 5 different and multiple joins, which I'm not allowed to share. Really sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're mistaken about the pivot part because there's no pivot happening here. This can be achieved with `IF()` or `CASE` expression functions added to a very basic MySQL syntax. So, this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

Will return you all columns and rows. Then this:

```
SELECT Seasonid, Product, Facility, Price, ProductType
FROM mytable;
```

is basically the same as the query before-that will return all columns and rows. Only difference is here we're explicitly defining all the column names from the table. So, from here you only need to modify the `Facility` and `Price` part with conditional `IF()` or `CASE()` and define it twice in the `SELECT` section, like this:

```
SELECT seasonid,
       Product,
       CASE WHEN Facility='Montreal' THEN Price ELSE 0 END AS 'Montreal',
       CASE WHEN Facility='Mexico' THEN Price ELSE 0 END AS 'Mexico',
       ProductType
FROM mytable;
```

Or

```
SELECT seasonid,
       Product,
       IF(Facility='Montreal',Price,0) AS 'Montreal',
       IF(Facility='Mexico',Price,0) AS 'Mexico',
       ProductType
FROM mytable;
```

In which both queries are able to get your desired result.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cd52c80a32718d73d88d471d1ef94e29)